# Search for specific object

Tags: java

I have a list of objects, an example of an object is:

```
255, "Ben Nevis", "Highland", 1344.5, 56.796849, -5.003525
```

There are lots of objects in the list, and I want it to print out all the objects which would have the word "Ben" in them, but I am unsure of how to do this, and as my second field in object can have more than one name.

```
List<Mountains> list = Mountains.readMountains();
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.println("Please enter a Mountain name: ");
String search = "Ben"
if (list.contains(search)){
    System.out.println("true");
}
else{
    System.out.println("no");
}
```

Comment: Well how *would* you do it if it was an array? what's stopping you doing pretty much the same?

Comment: can you use an enhanced for loop version of your Array solution?

Comment: basically, you can iterate through the list and for each item check the name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to iterate over every entry in your list, then check if the `Name` property (which is a String) contains your search term:

```
for(Mountains m:list){
  if(m.getName().contains(search)){
    System.out.println(m);
  }
}
```

This assumes that a Mountain's name can be accessed using `getName()`.

In your current code, you check (using `contains`) if a list of `Mountains` objects contains `String` object with the value of `"Ben"` which is never gonna be true.

Comment: I suspect your class ``Mountains`` has some member fields, one of them being ``name``. You need to compare that name to your search term.

Answer (score 1):

```
list.stream().filter(m->m.getName().contains(search)).forEach(System.out::println);
```

and if you want something more fancy you can try this :)

the code above will print all matches containing that "search".
If you want to check if it is found you can try this:

```
list.stream().filter(m->m.getName().contains(search)).findAny().isPresent()
```

These are nice **1-liners** from **Java 8** solving your question.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly you want to check for a string with a specific char sequence in a list of objects?

I would do something like this:

```
    String keyword = "Ben";
    Object[] objects = new Object[] { 255, "Ben Nevis", "Highland", 1344.5, 56.796849, -5.003525};

    for(Object obj : objects)
        if(obj instanceof String)
            if(((String) obj).contains(keyword)) {// Response here}
```

Comment: that comma-separated list is *one* list item (a mountain) represented as a string, not the various entries of the list.

Comment: Ah thought the input was like raw data or something

Answer (score 0):

```
String search = "Ben";
values.forEach(value-> {
    if (value.getName().contains(search)) {
        System.out.println("True");
    } else {
        System.out.println("False");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

So if I'm correct you have a class that contains all the data that you have writen as an example and you store it that information in a list.

So you can use a for loop to go through the list and then compare the thing you looking for with the information you have inside the list.

```
 List<Mountains> list = Mountains.readMountains();
 Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

 System.out.println("Please enter a Mountain name: ");
 String search = "Ben"

 for(int i=0;i<list.size()-1;i++){

  if (list.get(i).mountainName.equals(search)){

    System.out.println("Using list.get(i) you print all the data that has 
                       the same name as your search");
    }

  }
```